# How to select and update records in one table by matching ids from it with another table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I'm using **MySQL and phpMyAdmin**.

I'm a newbie to the database, RDBMS, SQL queries and all this stuff.

I've one database table called `user` which has following fields :

```
user_id(primary key) Data type : int(10) 
user_group_id Data type : smallint(4)
```

I've another database table called `user_field` which has following fields :

```
user_id(primary key) Data type : int(10) 
country_child_id Data type : mediumint(8)
```

Now I want select query and update query for above tables.

In select query it should return me the results from table `user_field` where `user_group_id = 6 and user.user_id = user_field.user_id`.

In update query I want to update the `country_child` field(`country_child = 1398`) from table `user_field` where `user_group_id = 6 and user.user_id = user_field.user_id`.

Can some one please help me in building my queries?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try to get the records you want to update by using INNER JOIN. You can try this query:

```
UPDATE a
SET a.country_child_id = 1398
FROM user_field AS a
INNER JOIN user AS b ON a.user_id = b.user_id
WHERE b.user_group_id = 6
```

Hope it helps.

EDIT:

FOR MySQL

```
UPDATE user_field
INNER JOIN user ON user.user_id = user_field.user_id
SET user_field.country_child_id = 1398
WHERE user.user_group_id = 6
```

I'm sorry the first update statement will only work in MSSQL. @Kendal is right, in MySQL SET clause comes after the INNER JOIN.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend a `where exists` clause for this type of update, like this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0852a/1

```
update user_field
set country_child_id = 1398
where exists (
  select * from user
  where user.user_id = user_field.user_id
  and user.user_group_id = 6
)
```

In the sample fiddle, you'll notice that two records are updated -- `user_id = 2` and `user_id = 6` are both part of `user_group_id = 6`.

EDIT:

I should mention that I like that syntax because I find it easy to read, though I should probably also mention that you can use a more explicit `inner join`. Just keep in mind that the syntax for mySQL seems to be slightly different than others, in that the `join` clause comes before the `set` clause.

At least, that's how I got it to work: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/de73e/1

```
update user_field
inner join user
on user.user_id = user_field.user_id
set country_child_id = 1398
where user.user_group_id = 6
```

Try them both and let me know which one's faster. Cheers!